# The Exception occured :- "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I want to store the DateTime data into the List .I have tried the below code but that throws the above exception.
     Please suggest some solution.

```
 SqlDataReader dr;
 con.Open();
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 List<DateTime> fdate = new List<DateTime>();

 try
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                fdate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
```

Comment: probably the the strings you are iterating are not in the expected format.what do you get on dr.toString. Also try using DateTime.TryParse instead

Comment: Show us your debugged value for dr

Comment: are you indexing the column?

Comment: Kuthe te? Ekach number

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I worked with DataReaders but don't you have to specify the column name or index? In your code you're trying to convert a DataReader to a DateTime object.

```
fdate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr.ToString()));
```

You need to specify the column in the DataReader to convert:

```
fdate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["column name"].ToString()));
```

And even then you're gonna need to check for nulls prior to doing the conversion.

Comment: Hi Jack, I have tried your code its working, thanks for your help.

Comment: at what index of dr is your datetime?